# AJAX - Refresh DIV in PHP include every second - not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I have a DIV that is located in a PHP include file. All I am trying to do is refresh this DIV to show updated content every second (I realize this would be alot, just using 1 second for testing purposes). However, it does not work and I cant figure out why.

I am testing by simply updating the "My Content" text and saving it... nothing changes. Can't figure out what is wrong.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxCall() {
         jQuery.get("<?php echo get_template_directory() . '/inc/order-status-desktop.php' ;?>", function(data) {
            jQuery(".ajax-status").html(data);
        });
     };

    // Execute ajax call every 5 seconds
    setInterval(function() {
        ajaxCall();
    },1000);
</script>
```

**HTML in the PHP include file**

```
<div class="ajax-status">
    My content
</div>
```

Comment: Most ajax calls are not going to finish within a second consistently, especially with variable network latency.

Comment: Also your "PHP" is javascript, not PHP.  So is that javascript that is generated from a PHP file?

Comment: Not really clear how you are verifying any of this. Do some console logging in the complete callback to see how often requests are actually made and succeed and what gets returned for starters. Or simpler look in browser dev tools network and you can see all requests made and see what is returned there

Comment: phpscript a new language

Comment: Sorry, that has been changed to properly state Javascript. The Javascript is located in a PHP file in the footer.php section of my site.

I see nothing in Network other than a successful GET for bootstrap and my stylesheet??

Comment: That would suggest the script is not running on the page.  Verify that it is there and also make sure your network log is not filtering out xhr requests.

Comment: @Taplar the script is there when viewing the page source code, and when viewing the Network tab in Dev Tools its blank - nothing there.